# cocoa circular progressbar only animated when key pressed or mouse moved?

Tags: macos, cocoa, progress-bar, animated

I show the circular progressbar in NSPanel, when the panel first time opened, it works fine. When it is hidden, and opened again, the circular progressbar only animates when key pressed or mouse moved.

Comment: Did you stopped it, started it again? are you using binding to spin?

Comment: no stop/start. both binding/spin have this problem.

Comment: I tried to call makeKeyWindow etc to make it get focused, but not work. Wondering how to make progressbar heartbeat triggered.

Comment: can you share your code (not full proj only a sample proj) with me? mail me...

Comment: Please check the sample proj. It is a panel opened from statusbar. When click second time, the progress indicator even can not show without mouse/key action. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31232387/p.zip